# Measuring user activity?

Tags: force.com

Is there was any way I could measure the time taken by different individuals in updating SF.  Ideally I’d have liked to have gotten a total hours spent working on the system for each.

I know that I can access the login history, but I'm really trying to get a sense of user activity.

Thanks!

Comment: i am not sure about quantifying user activity in terms of time. Maybe try aggregating the total number of updates users do, and use those as differentiators.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box mechanism for this sort of data. In theory, one could build a Visualforce page or some JavaScript that is embedded in the sidebar to keep track of this information, but such an interface would be generally unreliable, but still better than no information at all.